# Getting weird output when using the modelsummary package in R to create an average partial effects table

Tags: r, coefficients, modelsummary

I am trying to present an average partial effects table of multiple binary-response models. Back in December last year, I had no issue calling `modelsummary` in a list of objects of the class `"margins"    "data.frame"` to produce a table like the one below:
[image]

However, when I try to call `modelsummary` on a list of `margins` or `marginaleffects` objects, I get the following:

```r
# Working example

df<-mtcars

df$cyl<-as.factor(df$cyl)

library(modelsummary)
library(tidyverse)
library(marginaleffects)

# Binary response Models

model1<-glm(am ~ mpg + cyl,
            data = df,
            family = quasibinomial(link = 'logit'))

model2<-glm(am ~ mpg + cyl,
            data = df,
            family = quasibinomial(link = 'probit'))

model3<-glm(am ~ wt + cyl,
            data = df,
            family = quasibinomial(link = 'logit'))

model4<-glm(am ~ wt + cyl,
            data = df,
            family = quasibinomial(link = 'probit'))

models<-list(model1,model2,model3,model4)

mfx<-lapply(models, marginaleffects)

modelsummary(mfx,
             output = 'markdown')
```

|  | Model 1 | Model 2 | Model 3 | Model 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mpg | 0.056 | 0.057 |  |  |
|  | (0.027) | (0.026) |  |  |
| cyl | 0.093 | 0.091 | 0.120 | 0.121 |
|  | 0.093 | 0.091 | 0.120 | 0.260 |
|  | 0.093 | 0.091 | 0.253 | 0.121 |
|  | 0.093 | 0.091 | 0.253 | 0.260 |
|  | 0.093 | 0.102 | 0.120 | 0.121 |
|  | 0.093 | 0.102 | 0.120 | 0.260 |
|  | 0.093 | 0.102 | 0.253 | 0.121 |
|  | 0.093 | 0.102 | 0.253 | 0.260 |
|  | 0.097 | 0.091 | 0.120 | 0.121 |
|  | 0.097 | 0.091 | 0.120 | 0.260 |
|  | 0.097 | 0.091 | 0.253 | 0.121 |
|  | 0.097 | 0.091 | 0.253 | 0.260 |
|  | 0.097 | 0.102 | 0.120 | 0.121 |
|  | 0.097 | 0.102 | 0.120 | 0.260 |
|  | 0.097 | 0.102 | 0.253 | 0.121 |
|  | 0.097 | 0.102 | 0.253 | 0.260 |
|  | (0.169) | (0.174) | (0.058) | (0.053) |
|  | (0.169) | (0.174) | (0.058) | (0.063) |
|  | (0.169) | (0.174) | (0.068) | (0.053) |
|  | (0.169) | (0.174) | (0.068) | (0.063) |
|  | (0.169) | (0.236) | (0.058) | (0.053) |
|  | (0.169) | (0.236) | (0.058) | (0.063) |
|  | (0.169) | (0.236) | (0.068) | (0.053) |
|  | (0.169) | (0.236) | (0.068) | (0.063) |
|  | (0.238) | (0.174) | (0.058) | (0.053) |
|  | (0.238) | (0.174) | (0.058) | (0.063) |
|  | (0.238) | (0.174) | (0.068) | (0.053) |
|  | (0.238) | (0.174) | (0.068) | (0.063) |
|  | (0.238) | (0.236) | (0.058) | (0.053) |
|  | (0.238) | (0.236) | (0.058) | (0.063) |
|  | (0.238) | (0.236) | (0.068) | (0.053) |
|  | (0.238) | (0.236) | (0.068) | (0.063) |
| wt |  |  | -0.533 | -0.556 |
|  |  |  | (0.080) | (0.072) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 | 32 | 32 | 32 |
| F | 2.157 | 2.707 | 4.417 | 5.832 |
| RMSE | 0.39 | 0.39 | 0.27 | 0.27 |

I get the following warning messages:

```
--- 
Objects of class 'NULL' are currently not supported.
Objects of class 'NULL' are currently not supported.
Objects of class 'NULL' are currently not supported.
Objects of class 'NULL' are currently not supported.
Warning message:
There are duplicate term names in the table. The `shape` argument of the `modelsummary` function can be used to print related terms together, and to label them appropriately. You can find the group identifier to use in the `shape` argument by calling `get_estimates()` on one of your models. Candidate group identifiers include: type, contrast. See `?modelsummary` for details.
```

I tried listening to the warning message and added a `shape` argument as `shape =  ~ term + contrast ~ model`, which results in a better table. But I still get the "objects of class NULL" warning and I also get another new column on my table:

|  |  | Model 1 | Model 2 | Model 3 | Model 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mpg | dY/dX | 0.056 | 0.057 |  |  |
|  |  | (0.027) | (0.026) |  |  |
| cyl | 6 - 4 | 0.097 | 0.091 | 0.120 | 0.121 |
|  |  | (0.169) | (0.174) | (0.058) | (0.053) |
|  | 8 - 4 | 0.093 | 0.102 | 0.253 | 0.260 |
|  |  | (0.238) | (0.236) | (0.068) | (0.063) |
| wt | dY/dX |  |  | -0.533 | -0.556 |
|  |  |  |  | (0.080) | (0.072) |
| Num.Obs. |  | 32 | 32 | 32 | 32 |
| F |  | 2.157 | 2.707 | 4.417 | 5.832 |
| RMSE |  | 0.39 | 0.39 | 0.27 | 0.27 |

I would like to know if there is any way to get rid of that warning message, and also how to ommit/edit the new column that appears in the table with the `shape` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer uses the development version of `modelsummary`, which can be installed as follows (make sure you restart R after install):

```r
library(remotes)
install_github("vincentarelbundock/modelsummary")
```

There are two main approaches:

1. Display term names and contrast identifiers in separate columns, and rename them using the `group_map` argument.
2. Use the `shape` argument to combine the `term` and `contrast` identifiers.

First, note that contrasts and slopes are uniquely identified by two columns: `term` and `contrast`

```r
library(modelsummary)
library(marginaleffects)

mod <- list(
    glm(am ~ factor(cyl), data = mtcars, family = binomial),
    glm(am ~ factor(cyl) + mpg, data = mtcars, family = binomial))

mfx <- lapply(mod, marginaleffects)

tidy(mfx[[1]])
#>       type term contrast   estimate std.error statistic      p.value
#> 1 response  cyl    6 - 4 -0.2987013 0.2302534 -1.297272 0.1945376094
#> 2 response  cyl    8 - 4 -0.5844156 0.1636389 -3.571373 0.0003551141
#>     conf.low  conf.high
#> 1 -0.7499897  0.1525871
#> 2 -0.9051419 -0.2636893
```

We can display terms and contrasts in separate columns using the `shape` argument:

```r
modelsummary(
    mfx,
    shape = term + contrast ~ model
)
```

|  |  | Model 1 | Model 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cyl | 6 - 4 | -0.299 | 0.097 |
|  |  | (0.230) | (0.166) |
|  | 8 - 4 | -0.584 | 0.093 |
|  |  | (0.164) | (0.233) |
| mpg | dY/dX |  | 0.056 |
|  |  |  | (0.027) |
| Num.Obs. |  | 32 | 32 |
| AIC |  | 39.9 | 37.4 |
| BIC |  | 44.3 | 43.3 |
| Log.Lik. |  | -16.967 | -14.702 |
| F |  | 3.691 | 2.236 |
| RMSE |  | 0.42 | 0.39 |

We can rename and reorder the groups with the `group_map` argument:

```r
modelsummary(
    mfx,
    group_map = c("8 - 4" = "High - Low", "6 - 4" = "Mid - Low", "dY/dX" = "Slope"),
    shape = term + contrast ~ model
)
```

|  |  | Model 1 | Model 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cyl | High - Low | -0.584 | 0.093 |
|  |  | (0.164) | (0.233) |
|  | Mid - Low | -0.299 | 0.097 |
|  |  | (0.230) | (0.166) |
| mpg | Slope |  | 0.056 |
|  |  |  | (0.027) |
| Num.Obs. |  | 32 | 32 |
| AIC |  | 39.9 | 37.4 |
| BIC |  | 44.3 | 43.3 |
| Log.Lik. |  | -16.967 | -14.702 |
| F |  | 3.691 | 2.236 |
| RMSE |  | 0.42 | 0.39 |

We can display terms and group identifiers in the same column by including an interaction in the `shape` formula:

```r
modelsummary(
    mfx,
    shape = term : contrast ~ model
)
```

|  | Model 1 | Model 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cyl 6 - 4 | -0.299 | 0.097 |
|  | (0.230) | (0.166) |
| cyl 8 - 4 | -0.584 | 0.093 |
|  | (0.164) | (0.233) |
| mpg dY/dX |  | 0.056 |
|  |  | (0.027) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 | 32 |
| AIC | 39.9 | 37.4 |
| BIC | 44.3 | 43.3 |
| Log.Lik. | -16.967 | -14.702 |
| F | 3.691 | 2.236 |
| RMSE | 0.42 | 0.39 |

We can then rename or omit using the `coef_*` arguments:

```r
modelsummary(
    mfx,
    shape = term : contrast ~ model,
    coef_rename = function(x) gsub("dY/dX", "(Slope)", x)
)
```

|  | Model 1 | Model 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cyl 6 - 4 | -0.299 | 0.097 |
|  | (0.230) | (0.166) |
| cyl 8 - 4 | -0.584 | 0.093 |
|  | (0.164) | (0.233) |
| mpg (Slope) |  | 0.056 |
|  |  | (0.027) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 | 32 |
| AIC | 39.9 | 37.4 |
| BIC | 44.3 | 43.3 |
| Log.Lik. | -16.967 | -14.702 |
| F | 3.691 | 2.236 |
| RMSE | 0.42 | 0.39 |

Comment: Thank you @Vincent, the merging of the two columns indeed works well for me. I discovered that the reason why I could produce the table in the image I included was because I had dichotomized my variables completely with 0-1 (as suggested by @FilippeO.Gonçalves). The new features certainly make this process more efficient. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot to discuss here:

**1**. The new column that appeared was necessary because of the variable `cyl`. Since the `glm` function dummifies categorical variables internally, you end up with 2 variables out of `cyl` (it have 3 categories, so 3 minus 1 to avoid perfect multicolinearity). The table have to distinguish them in some way.

**2**. The default style of summaries does not yet support a `"marginaleffects"` model class. It's a potential issue that you can open [here](https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/modelsummary/issues), helping the package development.

**3**. Unfortunately, I couldn't figured out how to include the F-statistic and the RMSE metric to the final table, so probably my answer is not complete in terms of desired output. This change of function behavior was weird.

```
# compatible style
options(modelsummary_get = "broom")

df <- mtcars

# manually dummifying
df$cyl4 <- ifelse(df$cyl == 4, 1, 0)
df$cyl6 <- ifelse(df$cyl == 6, 1, 0)

# (just avoiding excessive typing)
df <- subset(df, select = c("am", "cyl4", "cyl6", "mpg", "wt"))
glm2 <- function(x, y) glm(x, data = df, family = quasibinomial(y))

model1 <- glm2(am ~ . - wt,  "logit")
model2 <- glm2(am ~ . - wt,  "probit")
model3 <- glm2(am ~ . - mpg, "logit")
model4 <- glm2(am ~ . - mpg, "probit")

models <- list(model1, model2, model3, model4)
mfx <- lapply(models, marginaleffects::marginaleffects)

modelsummary::modelsummary(mfx, output = "markdown", gof_map = "nobs")
```

|  | Model 1 | Model 2 | Model 3 | Model 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cyl4 | -0.106 | -0.116 | -0.365 | -0.389 |
|  | (0.300) | (0.299) | (0.137) | (0.132) |
| cyl6 | 0.005 | -0.011 | -0.154 | -0.164 |
|  | (0.205) | (0.202) | (0.100) | (0.093) |
| mpg | 0.056 | 0.057 |  |  |
|  | (0.027) | (0.026) |  |  |
| wt |  |  | -0.533 | -0.556 |
|  |  |  | (0.080) | (0.072) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 | 32 | 32 | 32 |

Comment: Thank you. It actually is not necessary for me to present those stats, so that isn't a problem. I understood the thing about the column, I just wish I could edit the stuff in the column, changing dy/dx to something else, for instance. I'm also surprised that *marginaleffects* objects are not supported as they are mantained by Vincent too, and there is an example using that packge in the *modelsummary* vignettes.

Comment: Glad I've helped! Yeah, that incompatibility surprised me too.

Comment: I agree that the interop between the two package is not optimal. The warnings are a known problem, and the solution should be coming soon. Combining the two columns more easily would be a nice feature. I'm not exactly sure what's the best user interface for this, but I'll think about it. I'm on vacation now, but will look into this when I return. Thanks for using the packages!

Comment: @DanielSánchez I have added new functionality to the development version of the package and added an answer to illustrate the new functions. If you get a chance to try it, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @FilippeO.Gonçalves the new answer may also be of interest to you.